# undefined method 'split' NoMethodError in TextsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nomethoderror

I am trying to build a simple word counter but I am getting a no method error here is my code any help would be appreciated

**Controller**

```
lass TextsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :set_text, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


def index
 @texts = Text.all
end

def show
end

def new
 @text = Text.new
end

def edit
end

def create
 @text = Text.new(text_params)
 @counter = text.split.size


end
```

**View**

```
<%= form_for(@text) do |f| %>
```

```
<%= f.label :name %><br>
   <%= f.text_field :name %>
```

```
<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
```

Comment: My guess is, `Text` is a class inheriting from ActiveRecord? Please post your Text code.

Comment: More questions, what is `text`?

Comment: Ninigi I haven't added anything in there yet class Text < ActiveRecord::Base
end

Comment: +BroSatse Text is the scaffold name,i typed in this rails g Scaffold Text text:string for more information

Comment: Why not just change (at)counter= text.split.size to (at)counter = (at)text.split.size and then remove your before_action?

Answer (score 1):

`split` is a method that can be called on strings. You are trying to call it on a `Text` object. You probably are intending to call split on a member of the `Text` object. Something like this:

```
@counter = text.some_member_of_text.split.size
```

Comment: To be clear, the "some_member_of_text" part needs to be a field from your Text object. From your view, it seems that the field of interest on Text might be "name"? Have you tried @counter = text.name.split.size?

Comment: But as i said before i also have a no method error hence my form is not working at all ,it says @text is nil any help on that?

Comment: Nvm i fixed the no method error  however now my counter is nil and still doesnt show any output

Comment: So, you probably need to make sure that the field you call split on has a value, and before that you need to make sure that text_params contains what you want to initialize the Text object with. If the value is an empty string, split will give you [] which has a size of 0. It is difficult to troubleshoot without seeing the current state of your code. You made need to start another question.

Comment: The @text.name does have a value i checked that just the counter seems to be nil

Answer (score 0):

After you get the string, in order to use split you should set a pattern like:

```
@counter = text.split(//).size
```

'(//)' will split each char I think it's what your looking for. The default pattern, which is applied in your case since you don't define it, splits between the spaces according to the docs:

http://apidock.com/ruby/String/split